# Find the length of AB in Triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, triangles

In $\Delta ABC , m \angle A = 2 m \angle C$ , side $BC$ is 2 cm longer than side $AB$ . 
$AC = 5 $
What is $AB$ ?

Well I thought you can use trigonometry or Complete Pythagoras theorem , but I don't really know how to apply it

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Draw a diagram is always my advice when doing geometry ... well more than just geometry... and label what you have and what you want ... I think you will see more clearly then

Comment: Think Sine and cosine rules and you may get there more quickly than dropping a perpendicular and using Pythagoras ... your call

Comment: You have changed the question slightly !!! Now you say AB.AC=5   if you followed my advice on labelling sides you will get a little quadratic to enjoy

Comment: To complement @EthanBolker's comment, instead of simply saying that you thought of using $X$ or $Y$, you may consider adding to your question *why exactly did you think of applying $X$ (or $Y$)*.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Let $AB=x$ and $AD$ be bisector of $\Delta ABC$.

Thus, $$\Delta ABD\sim\Delta CBA,$$ which gives
$$\frac{BD}{x}=\frac{x}{x+2}$$ or
$$BD=\frac{x^2}{x+2},$$ which gives
$$DC=x+2-\frac{x^2}{x+2}=\frac{4x+4}{x+2}$$ and since
$$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BD}{DC},$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{x}{5}=\frac{\frac{x^2}{x+2}}{\frac{4x+4}{x+2}},$$
which gives $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|AB|=c$, $|BC|=a=c+2$,
$|AC|=b=5$, 
$\angle BCA=\gamma$,
$\angle CAB=\alpha=2\gamma$

By the sine rule we have

\begin{align} 
\frac{\sin\alpha}{a}
&=
\frac{\sin\beta}{b}
=\frac{\sin\gamma}{c}
,\\
\frac{\sin2\gamma}{c+2}
&=
\frac{\sin(\pi-3\gamma)}{5}
=\frac{\sin\gamma}{c}
.
\end{align}

By the rules based on 
[componendo and dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo),

\begin{align} 
\frac{\sin2\gamma}{c+2}
&=
\frac{\sin\gamma}{c}
=\frac{\sin2\gamma-\sin\gamma}{c+2-c}
=\frac{\sin2\gamma-\sin\gamma}{2}
,\\
\frac{\sin(3\gamma)}{5}
&=
\frac{\sin2\gamma-\sin\gamma}{2}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
2\sin(3\gamma)
-
5\sin2\gamma+5\sin\gamma
&=0
,\\
8\sin\gamma\cos^2\gamma-2\sin\gamma
-10\sin\gamma\cos\gamma+5\sin\gamma
&=0
,\\
8\cos^2\gamma
-10\cos\gamma+3
&=0
,
\end{align}

so $\cos\gamma$ 
must be either $\tfrac12$ or $\tfrac34$.
It follows that possible values for $\gamma$
are $60^\circ$ or $\arccos\tfrac34\approx41.41^\circ$.

But since $\beta=180^\circ-3\gamma$, 
$\gamma=60^\circ$ results in $\beta=0$, a degenerate case,
so the only suitable choice is

\begin{align} 
\cos\gamma&=\tfrac34
,\\
\frac{\sin\gamma}c&=
\frac{\sin2\gamma-\sin\gamma}2
,\\
c&=\frac{2\sin\gamma}{\sin2\gamma-\sin\gamma}
,\\
&=
\frac{2\sin\gamma}{2\sin\gamma\cos\gamma-\sin\gamma}
=
\frac{2}{2\cos\gamma-1}
=
\frac{2}{2\cdot\tfrac34-1}
=4.
\end{align}

Thus $\triangle ABC$ has sides $4,5$ and $6$cm.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: with the Theorem of cosines we get

$$c^2=(c+2)^2+25-2(c+2)\cdot 5\cos(\gamma)$$
and with the Theorem of sines we get

$$\frac{\sin(3\gamma)}{\sin(\gamma)}=\frac{c}{5}$$
With these equations you can eliminate $\gamma$ and then you can compute $c$